# Button not visible in view pager in jelly bean

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am making an application which contain a view pager
on click of button date picker alert comes but this button is not visible in jelly bean
it is visible in android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 versions but not in 4.1
in place of it there is a blank space on whose click date picker pop's up but button is not visible there
Please tell me how to make it visible

Comment: We need some code to start with (XML, Java etc)

Answer (score 0):

In Some Motorola and Samsumg Smartphones it happens, even i too experienced the same proble, Use fragment activity to fix the issue, then only it works fine.

Your issue is not in all JellyBean device, with the same company other jelly bean device some times it works fine ..